# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Nexus_5X_API_26], use -list-avds to see valid list

Tags: android, android-studio

Instalei o emulador tudo certo, porém, quando vou executar, está aparecendo este erro aí. 
Estou usando Linux Mint.

Comment: conseguiu resolver esse erro?